# I have a data frame in which its columns do not have name and I want to name them in RCPP?How can I do that?

Tags: rcpp

I am very new in Rcpp. I have a data frame in which its columns do not have name and I want to name them in Rcpp. How can I do that? That is, this data frame is an input and then I want to name its columns in the first step.
Please let me know how I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  We can modify the existing example in the [RcppExamples](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples) package (which you may find helpful, just as other parts of the Rcpp documentation) to show this.

In essence, we just reassign a `names` attribute.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List DataFrameExample(const DataFrame & DF) {

    // access each column by name
    IntegerVector a = DF["a"];
    CharacterVector b = DF["b"];
    DateVector c = DF["c"];

    // do something
    a[2] = 42;
    b[1] = "foo";
    c[0] = c[0] + 7; // move up a week

    // create a new data frame
    DataFrame NDF = DataFrame::create(Named("a")=a,
                                      Named("b")=b,
                                      Named("c")=c);

    // and reassign names
    NDF.attr("names") = CharacterVector::create("tic", "tac", "toe");

    // and return old and new in list
    return List::create(Named("origDataFrame") = DF,
                        Named("newDataFrame") = NDF);
}

/*** R
D <- data.frame(a=1:3,
                b=LETTERS[1:3],
                c=as.Date("2011-01-01")+0:2)
rl <- DataFrameExample(D)
print(rl)
*/
```

#### Demo

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/61616170/answer.cpp")

R> D <- data.frame(a=1:3,
+                 b=LETTERS[1:3],
+                 c=as.Date("2011-01-01")+0:2)

R> rl <- DataFrameExample(D)

R> print(rl)
$origDataFrame
   a   b          c
1  1   A 2011-01-08
2  2 foo 2011-01-02
3 42   C 2011-01-03

$newDataFrame
  tic tac        toe
1   1   A 2011-01-08
2   2 foo 2011-01-02
3  42   C 2011-01-03

R>
```

If you comment the line out you get the old names.

Comment: @eddelbuettel       Thank you very much for your answer. It is helpful. The thing is that the columns do not have any specific name. Let say something like this R> D <- data.frame(1:3, + LETTERS[1:3], + as.Date("2011-01-01")+0:2) then what should I do to access the columns or renaming them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is helpful. The thing is that the columns do not have any specific name. Let say something like this R> D <- data.frame(1:3, + LETTERS[1:3], + as.Date("2011-01-01")+0:2) then what should I do to access the columns or renaming them.

Comment: You can always index by existing names _as well as_ by position.  Assigning new names is independent of the existing names so I do not quite understand the question.